# How to rename an activity?

Tags: android

How to rename an activity in Android Studio.

Comment: What exactly is the question ? Do explain properly .

Comment: I tried to rename an activity in Android Studio by first refactor->rename the xml layout file then the .java file and finally the class name from the project pane on the left hand side but ended up in a desaster since the entire project broke.

Comment: @ADM I don't see why this question needs an explanation, the question is very clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Android Studio, then it is very simple to refactor the Activity name by simply, 
right click on activity name

1. Go to Refactor
2. Go to Rename
3. Select all checkbox of the popup and rename
4. Then press Refactor

I hope, it will work for you :)